# Rotating a matrix with roll/pitch/yaw

Tags: matrix, opengl-es-2.0, transformation, glkit

I want to apply some real-world transformation (from accelerometer/gyroscope/compass) to my model-view matrix. This way:

```
modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakeLookAt(cam.x, cam.y, cam.z,
                                       0.f, 0.f, 0.f,
                                       0.f, 1.f, 0.f);

GLKVector3 v = GLKVector3Normalize(x, y, z);    // accelerometer + gyro

float roll = asinf(-v.x);
float pitch = atan2f(v.y, -v.z);
float yaw = GLKMathDegreesToRadians(heading);   // compass

GLKMatrix4 m = GLKMatrix4Identity;
m = GLKMatrix4RotateX(m, pitch);
m = GLKMatrix4RotateY(m, roll);
m = GLKMatrix4RotateZ(m, yaw);

modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Multiply(m, m_modelViewMatrix);
```

It works. But there is a problem. When the phone is in "camera" (landscape) orientation, so the "Slide to unlock" is exactly vertical, **y** and **z** are both very close to zero, frequently changing their signs. So, atan2() returns some "random" values, and the scene is moving in the horizontal plane...

There must be a way to simplify the transition by creating a single matrix from `x`, `y`, `z`, and `heading` without losing the accuracy...

UPD: **[Found the problem!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock#Loss_of_a_degree_of_freedom_with_Euler_angles)** Can anyone explain how to apply the solution to my matrix?

Answer (score 0):

this should clarify what you need to do: http://tutorialrandom.blogspot.com/2012/08/how-to-rotate-in-3d-using-opengl-proper.html this will solve your gimbal lock issues.

as for the random values when holding your phone vertically, im not sure. maybe transform the orientation vector so that its values are always positive or something.